# dotNetInstaller and .NET 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, dotnetinstaller

I have a standard situation - my software requires .NET 4.0. I created dotNetInstaller package, and put Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Web Installer) (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) inside. But problem is when user has another version of Windows, than english, i.e. Russian. This .NET Framework can't be installed in such case. How to solve this problem? Of course, I can create dotnetinstaller with 2 languages and propose to select version, but:
1. User can have Russian version of Windows, but selects English
2. User can have another version of Windows, i.e. Spanish and he should have ability to install .NET Framework from dotnetinstaller.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the multilingual support? You can install different components based on the operating system language.

Regards,
Stenio